# Windows 10 transparent Icons on a white background

Tags: windows-10, icons

I've noticed that icons that are supposed to have a transparent background have a white background instead.

[image]

I've tried rebuilding the thumbnail/icon cache, tried sfc /scannow, tried in-place upgrade install, nothing has helped.

Comment: Try changing the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a program I used called 'SageThumbs'. It's a known issue with it and Windows 10.

Comment: Try the new version (2.0.0.23), it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the latest Windows 10 update (1703) I experienced the same problem.  I uninstalled SageThumbs 2.0.0.22 and installed the newest version (2.0.0.23) and the problem is resolved.